# How do I add styling display to one particular set attribute?

Tags: javascript, css, styling, setattribute

```
    getvalue(response) {
    const videobyte = document.createElement('videoblock');
    videobyte.setAttribute('background', response.background);
    videobyte.setAttribute('playbut', response.button);
    }
```

In this how do I apply display: none styling to 'playbut' setAttribute ?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question, it's not clear.

Comment: These values are coming from the backend source where there's an play button icon but I need to add another icon over there so I'm trying to hide the playbut attribute using display: none and then I can add another icon in that place

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute selector to access an element with a specific attribute.

```
const elementWithPlaybut = document.querySelector('videoblock[playbut]');
elementWithPlaybut.style.display = 'none'
```

Comment: It's not working, Icon is still there @elioRahi

Comment: Are you sure you're appending the element you created (videoblock) to the body? It won't work if the element doesn't exist.

Comment: Yup I'm sure, it's not working

Comment: My bad, I was setting the attribute as display not the style. Edited my answer, should work now.

Comment: After adding your edited answer now It says property 'style' doesn't exist on the type 'Element'